# Cannot use the following command: "heroku create"

Tags: heroku

[heroku create error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bdAG.jpg)

I'm trying to learn ruby on rail and I followed the heroku steps to the t.

when I enter "heroku create" i get the error message in the img.

Comment: You are missing an argument

Comment: This command doesn't require an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Windows. I guess my installed version of the Heroku CLI was outdated because all I did was [uninstall and reinstall](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#uninstalling-the-heroku-cli) the Heroku CLI and everything is working again.